# visual studio C# windows forms managing

Tags: c#, forms

How do I switch between forms while maintaining forms settings, design and values on each form?
I am using this method, but every time it creates new default form values and a new form.

Main form:

```cs
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        this.Hide();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Second form:

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main f1 = new Main();
        this.Hide();
        f1.Show();          
    }
```

I need to save this form's values every time I switch between them. How do I do this?

Comment: don't keep re-initializing them.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with visual studio

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are creating the new instace of Existing form . show that it is creating the Form newly.

**Solution :** You need to Reopen the Existing (Hidden) form from memory using the `Application.OpenForms[]`

Replave This:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Main f1 = new Main();
    this.Hide();
    f1.Show();          
}
```

With This:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form frm = Apllication.OpenForms["Main"];     
   frm.Show();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this declaration from button click handler

Instead do this

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.Hide();
    f2.ShowDialog();
}

private Main form = new Main();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Hide(); 
   form.Show();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Main form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = new Form2(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

In Form2 form

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
        Form1 form1;
        public Form2(Form1 _form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form1 = _form1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            form1.Show();

        }
}
```